# Scheduled VBA task and 'Application.OnTime'

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

I have the following [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) code which is working well. It's calling another VBA `Sub` without any trouble:

```
Public Sub AutoPrintMissingHistoric()
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rcs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim value_start, value_end As String
    Dim tmp As Date
    Dim wbRiskedge As Workbook
    Dim wsAccueil As Worksheet
    Dim wsHistoric As Worksheet

    Set wbRiskedge = Workbooks(StrWbRiskedge)
    Set wsAccueil = wbRiskedge.Worksheets(StrWsAccueil)
    Set wsHistoric = wbRiskedge.Worksheets(StrWsHistoricMissing)
    If FistTime = True Then
        Call Initialisation.CleanTab
    Else
        FistTime = True
        Call Initialisation.Initialisation
    End If
    vDelay = 5
    Cpt = Cpt + 1
    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDB)
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Get_missing_fixings")
    If Cpt <= wsAccueil.Range(ManualListLetter & "1").End(xlDown).Row Then
        Application.StatusBar = wsAccueil.Cells(Cpt, ManualListLetter).Text
        qdf.Parameters("arg1") = wsAccueil.Cells(Cpt, ManualListLetter).Value
        Set rcs = qdf.OpenRecordset
        j = 0
        i = 1
        flag = False
        If Not rcs.EOF Then
            rcs.MoveLast
            rcs.MoveFirst
            While Not rcs.EOF
                j = 0
                While j < rcs.Fields.Count
                    If flag = False Then
                        With Cells(i, j + 1)
                            If .Value = "" Then
                                .Value = rcs(j).Name
                                .Font.Bold = True
                                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                            End If
                        End With
                    Else
                        Cells(i, j + 1).Value = rcs(j).Value
                    End If
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                If flag = False Then
                    flag = True
                End If
                i = i + 1
                rcs.MoveNext
            Wend
            Call ChangeMinMax(rcs.RecordCount, CellMinDate, CellMaxDate, wsHistoric)
            Call ParseParameters
            Call SetReutersFunction
        End If
        rcs.Close
        qdf.Close
        db.Close
        wsHistoric.Calculate
        Application.StatusBar = wsAccueil.Cells(Cpt, ManualListLetter).Text & " - Next Function: FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue"
        sToCall = "FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue"
        MTimeGT = Time + TimeValue("00:00:" & vDelay)
        Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall
    End If
End Sub
```

I put the execution of this process in a scheduled task. But apparently my code is not well executed: the `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue` Sub is not called because Excel just closes.

I think it's because of `Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall`... What could be the reason?

Here you've the code of `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue`

```
Sub AutoFindMissingValue()
    Dim wbRiskedge As Workbook
    Dim wsAccueil As Worksheet
    Dim wsHistoric As Worksheet
    Dim i, nbResult As Long

    Set wbRiskedge = Workbooks(StrWbRiskedge)
    Set wsAccueil = wbRiskedge.Worksheets(StrWsAccueil)
    Set wsHistoric = wbRiskedge.Worksheets(StrWsHistoricMissing)
    If Left(wsHistoric.Range(ReutersFormula).Text, 13) Like "Retrieving...*" = True Then
        sToCall = "FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue"
        MTimeGT = Time + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall
        Exit Sub
    End If
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(DateColumn & ":" & DateColumn))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(ColumnResearchVResult & ":" & ColumnResearchVResult)) > 0 Then
        wsHistoric.Range(FirstCellResearchVResult & ":" & ColumnResearchVResult & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(ColumnResearchVResult & ":" & ColumnResearchVResult))).ClearContents
    End If
    nbResult = wsHistoric.Range(FirstResult).End(xlDown).Row
    wsHistoric.Range(ColumnResearchVResult & LineResearchVResult - 1).Value = "Results"
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(DateColumn & ":" & DateColumn)) > 1 Then
        wsHistoric.Range(FirstCellResearchVResult & ":" & ColumnResearchVResult & i).FormulaLocal = "=RECHERCHEV($" & DateColumn & "$" & LineResearchVResult & ":$" & DateColumn & "$" & i & ";" & FirstLockResult & ":$" & ValueResultColumn & "$" & nbResult & ";2;0)"
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = wsAccueil.Cells(Cpt, ManualListLetter).Text & " - Next Function: FindMissingValue.AutoPutResultInDb"
    sToCall = "FindMissingValue.AutoPutResultInDb"
    MTimeGT = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried debug-stepping through your code?

Comment: debug is not working with scheduled task... So I used `MsgBox` I put one in this `Sub` and one in the `Sub` named `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue`. The one in `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue` is never executed while the one before `Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall` is executed. So I think it's because of the `Application.OnTime` but I don't know how to solve it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application.OnTime` part is right and `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue` should be called without any problem (after 5 seconds). What might happen is that, during this 5 seconds period, the code continues running, goes back to where `AutoPrintMissingHistoric` was called from, and the workbook might be closed before these 5 seconds have passed (although, depending upon your exact conditions, the function should be called even despite the workbook is closed).

You can either reduce the waiting period (`vDelay = 1`, for example) or just call the function directly (`Call FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue`). Actually, I am not sure why you are calling the function by relying on `Application.OnTime`; using this is fine for "starting the process" (e.g., "I want my macro to be executed every day at 00:00"), but might drive to "messy situations" in case of being used on a regular basis.

If nothing of this works, please, provide the code of `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue` to take a look at it.

NOTE: after some further tests/discussions, I can confirm that the behavior of `OnTime` under these specific conditions is "too irregular". You should come up with a different approach to allow the waiting period you need or, in case of having to rely on `OnTime`, do an intensive trial-and-error to make sure that its behaviour is completely under control. This function is expected to be called once (opening the spreadsheet at certain time, for example) and thus you have to pay lots of attention when using it on different contexts (like this one: calling it inside a function).

Comment: As I replied to Mehow, debug is not working with scheduled task... So I used `MsgBox` I put one in this `Sub` and one in the `Sub` named `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue`. The one in `FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue` is never executed while the one before `Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall` is executed. So I think it's because of the `Application.OnTime` but I don't know how to solve it....

Comment: @Yumino please, read my answer. Either reduce vDelay to its minimum expression (1) or call the function directly (what is the exact point of using Application.OnTime on this context?). Otherwise, please provide the code for FindMissingValue.AutoFindMissingValue. The Application.OnTime in your code is rightly called, so we need more information to understand why it is not running OK on your computer (or, stop using it because, as said, I am not sure about the exact point of doing it).

Comment: I'm using `Application.OnTime` because in my sheets, I'm using a tool to get some external data. As you know, while you're executing VBA code, your excel Sheet is blocked. `Application.OnTime` is the only way I found to be sure the sheet will be refreshed during 5 seconds in my case. Which is enough to let the tool retrieves the data. So in my process `wsHistoric.Calculate` will refresh the sheet and launch the tool. `Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall` will let the tool doing his process because the excel sheet will be released by the VBA.

Comment: I can give the code of the other sub, but i'm sure he's working well. Without the scheduled task, all my subs are working well. But with the scheduled task, it stops at the end of this function

Comment: @Yumino how many times are you calling Application.OnTime? More than just this one, isn't it?

Comment: One on this function, and one on another function. But another function are not executed because it ends at this one

Comment: @Yumino I saw your code and confirmed what I thought: you are using Application.OnTime concurrently over and over and this drives to pretty messy situations (the waiting of the first called is overlapped with the next one, etc.).

Comment: @Yumino Can you please explain me why you cannot call AutoFindMissingValue directly? Which part in this function needs from a waiting period?

Comment: are you sure ? because in the scheduled task, it ends at the first one. but when I launched it myself, it's going well and executing all my process (around 30m)

Comment: It's not in this function. it's an addin tool to my excel. When I refresh my sheet. The window of the tool opened. He needs some time to retrieves the values. For this reason I give him this waiting period.

Comment: @Yumino, as said in my answer; if you execute Application.OnTime just once (to start the calculations, regularly, for example), it would work fine and accurately. If you start to user it regularly (inside the code, to call functions), weird things happen. Imagine this scenario: Application.Ontime has to wait 5 seconds but in the second second you close the Excel file and open it away (the original waiting period would continue being there and you have started a new one). The best way to have a solid/reliable macro with Ontime is using it as less and in controllable environments.

Comment: So do you know how to release the excel sheet during a while in my VBA code ?

Comment: @Yumino I am not sure what you mean with that. What I see in the function you are calling, are simple references to the spreadsheet/functions on it. Bear in mind that all the writing performed in the calling sub (AutoPrintMissingHistoric) is automatically stored and the next function will see these values automatically, you don't need to wait.

Comment: @Yumino release? I am not getting it. Please, explain what is exactly expected to happen during the 5secs waiting period.

Comment: good answer, you guys consider [continuing discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35576/excel-chat)

Comment: I mean when I do the `wsHistoric.Calculate`, my sheet will be refreshed, and the tool will be launched. But the external tool needs some time for doing his process (connecting, retrieving data, etc.). If i'm not doing `Application.OnTime MTimeGT, sToCall`, my sheet stay 'fixed' and the tools is not doing his process.

Comment: @mehow, the common-sense bringer LOL, sure, will do right away.

Comment: @Yumino I can explain everything via chat, better.

Comment: OK apparently the problem is solved. I follow your advice about using multi-threading process by launching the process in another Excel application. Thank you for your advice guys and for your great help ;)

Comment: @Yumino I am happy to read that you finally solved your problem. It was nice from Mehow to contribute to solve this.